# How to run Mahout jobs on Spark Engine?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mahout

Currently I’m doing some document similarity analysis using Mahout RowSimilarity Job. This can be easily done be running command ‘mahout rowsimilarity…’ from the console. However I noticed that this Job is also supported to be run on Spark engine. I wonder to know how I can run this Job on Spark Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MLlib alternate of mahout in spark. All library in MLlib are processing in distributed mode(Map-reduce in Hadoop).

In Mahout 0.10 provide job execution with spark.

More detail Link
http://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/play-with-shell.html

step to setup spark with mahout.

1 Goto the directory where you unpacked Spark and type sbin/start-all.sh to locally start Spark

2 Open a browser, point it to http://localhost:8080/ to check whether Spark successfully started. Copy the url of the spark master at the top of the page (it starts with spark://)

3 Define the following environment variables:
    export MAHOUT_HOME=[directory into which you checked out Mahout]
    export SPARK_HOME=[directory where you unpacked Spark]
    export MASTER=[url of the Spark master]

4 Finally, change to the directory where you unpacked Mahout and type bin/mahout spark-shell, you should see the shell starting and get the prompt mahout>. Check FAQ for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [link](http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html).It uses new mahout 0.10 and works uses spark server.